# String description of NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I have the following code:

```
[ [NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale: @"yyyy-MM-dd" ]
```

I want it to return a date in the following format: "2009-04-23"

But it returns: Thursday, April 23, 2009 11:27:03 PM GMT+03:00

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. Instead try [`descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:)

```
[[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d"
                                    timezone:nil
                                      locale:nil];
```

Also note that the method is expecting a different format than the one in your question. The full documentation for that can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007972-SW1).

EDIT: Though as Mike noted, you really should be using `NSDateFormatter`. There are some problems with `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timezone:locale:` that Apple mentions in the documentation.

Comment: @NicHubbard: This method is neither deprecated nor depreciated. At least as of 10.6 (the current version of Mac OS X).

Comment: But it does seem to be for iOS. Time to be verbose and use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: This might be available for Mac OS X but not iOS!

Answer (score 91):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];  // delete this line if your project uses ARC
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Comment: For locale reasons, you shouldn't set the date & time formats explicitly. Instead, use the locale-friendly styles:

    `[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];`

Comment: @GrahamPerks that's not always true. What if, for example, you're generating a date to send to a web api which will need to be parsed by the server?

Comment: Fair enough. I'm pointing out not to blindly copy the code in the answer; if the string is going to be seen by a user, it needs a tweak.

Comment: Then I'll add my 2 cents as well.  Most users do not know how to change system date formats, and a lot of apps do not respect them, so just because the system has a certain format, doesn't mean the user likes it or it is good to use.  Just my experience after 10+ years in the GUI design business.

Answer (score 10):

Also note that for most cases, `NSDateFormatter` is to be preferred for its flexibility.

There's also a significant performance benefit to be had from re-use of date formatters in many apps.

Comment: You are kidding me right? Just look at the docs to see how configurable it is!

Comment: I do not kid. I am merely asking which of the many and varied flexibilities which NSDateFormatter has actually has any bearing on the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `NSDate -descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:` available (I don't believe iPhone/Cocoa Touch includes this) you may need to use [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) and monkey around with some C-style strings.  You can get the UNIX timestamp from an NSDate using `NSDate -timeIntervalSince1970`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is standard Cocoa as descriptionWithLocale does not exist on the iPhone, either.

Comment: Good point. I did see another similar question that was iphone-related, so I think I'll re-post this response there.